# Autofac - how to filter autowired properties

Tags: .net, properties, filter, autofac, autowired

Is it possible to configure Autofac registration so it AutoWired properties on the registered class but not all of them?

I would like to indicate which properties should not be autowired.

Comment: How about making the properties that should not be wired, read-only?

Comment: That wouldn't work in my case. I need the properties to have public get, set accessors, but still would like to leave them not autowired.

Comment: Hm... Autofac will only set those properties for which the container have a service. Do you have service type properties that should not be set by the container?